# Why proxy doesn't work with python's requests?

Tags: python, proxy

I try this code, proxies are good, but I see my ip in logger, using them. Help, my 'requests' is 2.19.1. Some of my code:

```
for [...]:
    url=''
    proxy={'http':'http://'+get_proxy()} #works
    useragent={'User-Agent':get_useragent()}
    try:
        r=requests.get(url,headers=useragent,proxies=proxy)
        print('sent')
    except:
        print('error')
```

So I can skip bad proxies, but good dont work (I want to change my IP with them, but i actually see my own IP).

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Try to remove the try/except and post the error you get.

Comment: Your problem is poorly explained, please[edit] the question to provide information as explained on [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: i use 'try' to skip bad proxies only. With good i have not error but i still see my oun ip.

Comment: to explaine more, edited

Comment: solved, proxy must be ssl